# JavaScript: loading/including another JS file when using JSONP

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

Let me preface this by saying I have read [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file) to understand how to load one JS file in another JS file.  My use case is a little different than the original question.

I have two servers, A and B.  Server A hosts our content management system.  Server B hosts our downloadable files.  On server B, we have some auto-generated metadata files that are essentially JSON files that contain metadata about our downloadable packages.

I have successfully created a test situation where the content management system on server A is able to pull in and display the metadata from server B using JSONP.  However, in this test, I had to edit the metadata file to add a function and an eval statement, like this:

```
/**
 * Get the value of a querystring
 * @param  {String} field The field to get the value of
 * @param  {String} url   The URL to get the value from (optional)
 * @return {String}       The field value
 * http://gomakethings.com/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-querystring-with-native-javascript/
 */
var getQueryString = function( field, url ) {
    var href = url ? url : location.href;
    var reg = new RegExp( '[?&]' + field + '=([^&#]*)', 'i' );
    var string = reg.exec(href);
    return string ? string[1] : null;
};

var json = {
  "product": "hello world",
  "version": "1.2.3",
  "date": "October 22, 2015",
  "release_notes": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>" };

eval( getQueryString("callback") + '(' + JSON.stringify(json) + ');' );
```

Ideally, the metadata file would contain only the metadata, such as this:

```
{
  "product": "hello world",
  "version": "1.2.3",
  "date": "October 22, 2015",
  "release_notes": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>"
}
```

And I would have a second file to load the function and the metadata.  I have tried doing the following in the "loader" file, but in the AJAX call, the status code is 0 instead of 200 because the address in the browser bar is server A and the address where I'm trying to get the metadata file from is server B.

```
/**
 * Get the value of a querystring
 * @param  {String} field The field to get the value of
 * @param  {String} url   The URL to get the value from (optional)
 * @return {String}       The field value
 * http://gomakethings.com/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-querystring-with-native-javascript/
 */
var getQueryString = function( field, url ) {
    var href = url ? url : location.href;
    var reg = new RegExp( '[?&]' + field + '=([^&#]*)', 'i' );
    var string = reg.exec(href);
    return string ? string[1] : null;
};

var json = "";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var filename = "http://server-B.com/" + getQueryString("file") + ".json";
alert(filename);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 1) { alert("server connection established"); }
    if (xhr.readyState === 2) { alert("request received"); }
    if (xhr.readyState === 3) { alert("processing request"); }
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) { alert("request finished status=" + xhr.status); }
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        json = xhr.responseText;
        alert(json);
    }
};
xhr.open("GET", filename, true);
xhr.send();


eval( getQueryString("callback") + '(' + json + ');' );
```

Is there some way for me to dynamically load a JSON file into a JS file, and call the JS file via JSONP from another domain?

Comment: It is still a little bit unclear what you try to achieve… JSONP was a "trick" to load content and execute a predefined function from any server through a script tag, which is not limited by cross-origin policy. JSONP is no longer recommended because of many security threats. Instead, you should have a look at [CORS - cross-origin HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). This should allow you to make a normal AJAX request on your server B whereas your main script comes from server A.

Comment: BTW, if my understanding is correct, you are trying to evaluate some code defined in `location`??? That could be a serious leak for a phishing attack…

Comment: Thanks, got it working with straight JSON and CORS on an S3 bucket.